# React react-number-format applies wrong decimalScale

Tags: javascript, reactjs

`"react-number-format": "^4.0.8"`

I guess there is something wrong with the rounding (or with my understanding):

```
  render() {
    const { input, smValue = 10 } = this.props;
    console.log("render");

    return <Col sm={smValue}>
      <NumberFormat
       value={input.value}
       customInput={FormControl} 
       decimalScale={I need 20 here}
       onValueChange={({value}) => {
         console.log("onValueChange value: ", value);
         input.onChange(value);
        }}
      />
    </Col>;
 }
```

`input` is an object that has `name: "", onBlur: ƒ (event), onChange: ƒ (event), onDragStart: ƒ (event),  onDrop: ƒ (event), onFocus: ƒ (event)`

In both cases I am setting `1.5555555+` value

`decimalScale={15}` Correct:

```
onValueChange value:  1
render
onValueChange value:  1.
onValueChange value:  1.5
render
onValueChange value:  1.55
render
....
onValueChange value:  1.55555555555555
render
onValueChange value:  1.555555555555555
render
```

`decimalScale={20}` (even starts after 16) Incorrect:

```
onValueChange value:  1
render
onValueChange value:  1.
onValueChange value:  1.5
render
onValueChange value:  1.55
render
onValueChange value:  1.555
render
onValueChange value:  1.5555
render
onValueChange value:  1.5554
render
onValueChange value:  1.55545
render
onValueChange value:  1.55544
...
render
onValueChange value:  1.555444555555343
render
onValueChange value:  1.5554445555553435
render
onValueChange value:  1.55544455555534355
onValueChange value:  1.555444555555343555
```

Render applies twice when numbers are changing.
Can I do anything to fix it?

Comment: because > JavaScript Numbers are Always 64-bit Floating Point. so the maximum number of decimals is 17. read this [doc](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_numbers.asp)

Comment: @DragonWhite ok but I am simply filling the input. I am not doing any operations with decimal numbers greater than 17. As you can see I am receiving `1.5554` on the 4th sign. Maybe there is something going inside the formatter?

Comment: could you explain to me about the input props of this component?